How to set guest hostname using pyvmomi?
I'm using the community sample for pyvmomi to clone a VM from a template.
However, the cloned VM has the same hostname (computer name) as the template.
Is there a way to set the computer name of the cloned VM during the cloning process?
I've looked at the VMWare documentation for CloneSpec, but I couldn't find anything related to that. The only thing I found was CustomizationSpec, but this refers to the network hostname, not the computer (OS) name.
